# jquery - swaping submit button class and text on focus

Tags: jquery

got a problem with my jquery config since some days:

i got an input field and submit button next to it.

currently the button changes its text and class, if input field is focused.
so far so good.... but if i click or focus the button, it switches back to initial 
state. but it should not.

So i want to achieve: If input field OR button is focused/clicked than change button

please see my jsfiddle

```
$('.swap-submit > input').bind('focus blur', function() {
  var btn = $(this).siblings('span').find('button');
  btn.toggleClass('btn-submit-text btn-submit-icon').html(btn.text() == 'Find' ? '-Icon-' : 'Find');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NPFF3/

Comment: Side note, as of jQuery 1.7, the `.on()` method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document.

Answer (score 0):

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/NPFF3/4/

If you want to change button's class and text when input or button is focused, then:

```
$('input,button').bind('focus', function () {
  var btn;
  if($(this).prop('tagName').toLowerCase()=='button'){
      btn = $(this);
  }
  else{
      btn = $(this).siblings('span').find('button');
  }

  btn.toggleClass('btn-submit-text btn-submit-icon').html(btn.text() == 'Find' ? '-Icon-' : 'Find');

  });
```

Or, if you need to change button's class and text only on input focus, then :

```
$('input').bind('focus', function () {
    btn = $(this).siblings('span').find('button');      
    btn.toggleClass('btn-submit-text btn-submit-icon').html(btn.text() == 'Find' ? '-Icon-' : 'Find');
  });
```